# WSO2 API Manager Admin Service : how to create application

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

i'm trying to create an application with the Admin Services from a webservice. So i called the admin Service "IdentityApplicationManagementService" and i use the function "createApplication". 
To test it, i used SoapUI and it worked fine. I can see the App from the management console in the "Service provider" section. But when i log in the API Store as admin (for example), i can't see the application created.. So i can't subscribe any API with it. 
So does somebody know how to make the application created visible on the Store ?

Comment: Are you using a standalone APIM pack or APIM pack with IS as KM features installed?

Comment: I use a standalone APIM pack

Answer (score 0):

Apps created via admin services will not be available in store side. If you need to create applications using a REST service, you can use store api explained in [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Store). It will be available in the API store.

1. Login to Store :

   ```
   curl    -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
   ```
2. Create and application via store api. :

   ```
   curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/application/application-add/ajax/application-add.jag -d 'action=addApplication&application=NewApp1&tier=Unlimited&description=&callbackUrl='
   ```